# Как правильно писать вопрос и тут же ответить на него?

Tags: пунктуация

Я пишу так:

> Что в итоге получится – попробую ответить далее.
>   Теперь почему ему нездоровится – загадка.

Может, нужно знак вопроса добавлять или ещё как-то поправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Что в итоге получится – попробую ответить далее**.

Изъяснительное придаточное предложение в препозиции, в этом случае рекомендуется тире.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

1. Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует:
   1) придаточная изъяснительная: Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять (Г.);

2) **Почему ему теперь нездоровится – (это) загадка.**

Можно рассматривать как БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение) с пропущенным местоимением ***это***.

В обоих случаях делается увеличенная пауза, которая на письме обозначается тире.

Примечание:  Доверяйте интонации (она Вам подскажет правильный вариант), но и правила тоже учите.